# How to choose which function is called first in Node Js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, ethereum

I am currently using an Ether package and NodeJS to learn a few things.

Here is my code:

```
var ethers = require('ethers');
var providers = require('ethers').providers;

var infuraProvider = new providers.InfuraProvider(process.argv[3]);

infuraProvider.getBlockNumber().then(function(blockNumber) {
  console.log("Current block number: " + blockNumber);
});

infuraProvider.getGasPrice().then(function(gasPrice) {
  console.log("Current gas price: " + gasPrice.toString());
});
```

It basically gets the network from my argument, and then get blockNumber and gasPrice.
So if run this, here is what I get:

```
Current block number: 5083149
Current gas price: 8000000000
```

Which is what I want. But sometimes, it gives the gas price BEFORE the block number, like that:

```
Current gas price: 8000000000
Current block number: 5083149
```

How can I edit my code so it always give the block number first? I tried to play with the `.then` keyword, but didn't manage to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Call getGasPrice() function inside the .then() of getBlockNumber(), or take a look to async - await calls.

Comment: @IkerVázquez my god. Tried EVERYTHING except calling the getGasPrice() function insde the .then(). It works well, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
infuraProvider.getBlockNumber().then(function(blockNumber) {
    console.log("Current block number: " + blockNumber);
    infuraProvider.getGasPrice().then(function(gasPrice) {
        console.log("Current gas price: " + gasPrice.toString()); 
    });
});
```

Otherwise you're basically racing the two Promises and it may not be deterministic which one goes first.

Or, in an async function, you can do:

```
var printDetails = async function()
{
    let blockNumber = await infuraProvider.getBlockNumber();
    console.log("Current block number: " + blockNumber);
    let gasPrice = await infuraProvider.getGasPrice();
    console.log("Current gas price: " + gasPrice.toString());
}

printDetails();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. Just put my getGasPrice function into the first then, as you did in your first code. Though, what are the differences between the first example and the async function one? Which one is the best to use?

Comment: That should do it. It's a very common pattern to chain promises and if you are calling say 10 functions you might want to structure your code a little differently. You wouldn't want to nest 10 deep.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
infuraProvider.getBlockNumber().then(function(blockNumber) {
  console.log("Current block number: " + blockNumber);
  return infuraProvider.getGasPrice();
}).then(function(gasPrice) {
  console.log("Current gas price: " + gasPrice.toString());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. What is the difference between this way and putting the getGasPrice function into the .then() of getBlockNumber()? Like Terry Lennox did.

Comment: The advantage of using this approach is to avoid nesting of function, right now you have only 2 functions so not an issue but if functions are more it'll create a problem.

Comment: Okay thank you for explaining. Thanks to both of you I understood it all. Thanks again!